# Windows 8 store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

Hi All i just want to redesign my website as Windows Store app.

Imagine that i'm done with the above exercise.

I have 2 very basic questions.

1. Can i deploy the Windows Store app in IIS just like website? If i'm not able to host via IIS how can my website users access the app?
2. Do Windows Store app require Windows 8 environment?

Kind help please.Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allen provided some great resources above.  In addition, here are some clarifications:

> 1. Can i deploy the Windows Store app in IIS just like website? If i'm not able to host via IIS how can my website users access the app?

No, you can't deploy a Windows Store app to IIS.  Windows Store apps can be downloaded from the Windows Store by your users.  You will need to maintain a separate website codebase for your web users.

> 1. Do Windows Store app require Windows 8 environment?

Yes, you need the Windows 8 operating system to develop the app as a developer, and to use the apps as an end user.

Answer (score 3):

Here're two good articles from Windows Store apps development support blog I think can help you.

[Migrate an ASP.NET Web Forms application to Windows Store app](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2012/11/13/migrate-an-asp-net-web-forms-application-to-windows-store-app.aspx)

[Migrate ASP.NET MVC application to Windows Store apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2012/11/12/migrate-asp-net-mvc-application-to-windows-store-apps.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A windows 8 app developed as HTML5 is basically nothing but zipped HTML+JavaScript+Resources, so as long as you are not using the exposed Windows Runtime javaScript objects , you should be able to deploy it to any Web Server by unzipping it.

But this is just a possibility, and in real life you don't write a Win8 app without referring to windows libraries in WinJS